# Attempting to print Strings on seperate lines

Tags: java

While writing a project for a non CS class I ran into a problem. The project i had in mind is a type of quiz, wherein the user is asked a question and is given multiple choices for answers. Now, I intended to type these questions into a .txt file and use a file scanner to read them in, and create an array of questions like so:

```
public static String[] questionToString(Scanner sf) {
    String temp = "";
    String[] questions = new String[Q];
    int i = 0;
    while(sf.hasNext()){
        for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        temp += sf.nextLine();
    }
    questions[i] = temp;
    i++;
    temp = "";
    return questions;
}
```

However, this code when tested would return something along the lines of:

```
Question 1 abcd
```

as opposed to:

```
Question 1
a 
b
c
d
```

I want each character to be placed on it's own line, like in the second example. **How can I do this while printing the strings?** (`System.out.println()`)

Eventually, I plan to put them on a DrawingPanel with the questions lined up below.

Thanks!

Comment: This code is really confusing.  Your curly braces don't pair up.  You should fix that.

Comment: I'd suggest, to use JSON for your configuration files. You would gain more flexibility (i.e. you could have qurstions/answers that are more than one line), the configuration is easier to read, and it is also easier to read the configuration into your program and handle questions and answers in a structured way (have Question class, Answer class, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Use `"\n"` to add an extra line in addition to the line `println()` already appends:

```
System.out.println(your_var + "\n")
```

Comment: I attempted to use \n but it wasn't working, ill try again though. Also the end goal is not to print out the strings, but to be able to put them into an array format while maintaining the spaces in between each line.

Comment: show me the code where array questions is getting utilized

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are adding questions lines to a string. So make a small change to the following line:

```
temp += sf.nextLine() + "\n";
```

Of course, the newline char depends on which environment you are running (`\n` or `\r\n`).

Answer (score 0):

Best way to append many strings into one with a new line character after each one is to use StringBuilder. I have rewritten your code using StringBuilder

```
  public static String[] questionToString(Scanner sf) {
   StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
   String[] questions = new String[Q];
   int i = 0;
   while(sf.hasNext()){
    for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
    temp.append(sf.nextLine());
    temp.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
   questions[i] = temp.toString();
   i++;
   temp = new StringBuilder();
   return questions;
```

}

NOTE: Please don't append `/n` with your string as the new line character differs for different operating system. I will advise you to use `System.lineSeparator()`, this will append the new line character depending on the operating system you are running you code on.